# How to modify ckeditor placeholder plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, placeholder

I would like to modify the rendered result of ckeditor placeholder plugin and here s the  different manipulations i ve tried:

- I added another element to placeholder dialog (manipulating dialog/placeholder.js file) and it s working fine
- but for plugin.js file, all changes are not implemented. I even deleted the file, but nothing actually happened.

I need to display the cke_placeholder class and a data-type attribute to the source code of the placeholder rendered (example below)

```
<span class="cke_placeholder" data-type=1>[[content]]</span>)
```

Comment: Any idea about the request above? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, it worked by only manipulating plugin.js file.
I suppose it was a cache problem